# fit flex item cross-axis size to content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the flex-container with column direction info__text-container whose width is 150px. Inside I have two spans with text that can be wrapped to next line.
What I want is flex item shrink to content when text wraps, but it always remains 150px.
Words are generated dynamically, so I can't just use `<br/>` or smth. 
[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7pHw.png)
[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XSmR.png)

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.info__block-margin {
  margin-right: 48px;
}

.info__number {
  font-size: 40px;
}

.info__number-margin {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.info__text-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 150px;
}

.info__text {
  min-width: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.info__subtext {
  min-width: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <div class="info info__block-margin">
      <p class="info__text-container">
        <span class="info__text">Socially SignificantSo </span>
        <span class="info__subtext">Socially SignificantSocial</span>
      </p>
      <span class="info__number">98</span>
    </div>
    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[EXAMPLE](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-snyder-tz1f0)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just to be clear what is the difference between what you have and what you want?

Comment: @Nelles the space between the text and the number

Comment: It's normal behaviour, if you add a `<br>` in between your words then you will get what you want or set a fixed width for that block

Comment: @Huangism content is generated dynamically, so I can't do that. I'll add this information to question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current HTML structure, you can set a `flex-basis: 0` to your `.info__text-container` class. If you'd like to know what setting the basis to 0 does, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47579078/11938059).